# Variable image height based on content height

Tags: html, tailwind-css

Do you have any ideas about how I can use Tailwind CSS to make the image from the left div have a variable height, based on the content from the right div?

[image]

This is what I have now:

```
<div className="bg-ez-white dark:bg-ez-bg-dark shadow-lg sm:w-full rounded-xl flex flex-col md:items-stretch md:flex-row overflow-hidden my-4">
  <div className="md:w-1/2 bg-rose-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dCpwjBj.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div className="bg-rose-400 h-fit md:w-1/2 flex flex-col p-4 md:p-6">
    <div className="font-ez-font-inter font-bold text-sm md:text-base text-ez-accent-lighter dark:text-ez-bg-light flex space-x-2">
      {categories.map(category => (
      <span key={category}>{category}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
    <h1 className="font-ez-font-inter text-3xl md:text-4xl font-bold">{title}</h1>
    <p className="font-ez-font-poppins text-ez-accent-light text-base md:text-lg dark:text-ez-bg-light">
      There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
    </p>
    <div className=" flex items-end flex-row-reverse">
      <p className="font-ez-font-inter font-bold text-sm md:text-base text-ez-accent-lighter dark:text-ez-bg-light">{createdAt}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. that answear would be very short:-)  You have to add only `h-auto` in this line:

`<div className="bg-rose-400 h-fit md:w-1/2 flex flex-col p-4 md:p-6 h-auto">`

**working example**
https://play.tailwindcss.com/GdVJp8k9zA

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. I think that the problem is the size of the image.

Comment: @CătălinAvasiloaie take a look: https://play.tailwindcss.com/GdVJp8k9zA . You use tailwindCss!? i had to change className to class.

Comment: @CătălinAvasiloaie and it looks very well :-)

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem... The fact is that I want the image to have the max height of the text from the right.

Comment: @CătălinAvasiloaie ok. i really misunderstood. In this case, I would make the image a background image and then add the class 'h-car' to the image container.

Comment: Yes, it kinda works now, but I don't know anything about the 'h-car' property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240252/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-ctlin-avasiloaie).